# My discord bot turn offline but my script still work

Tags: api, discord.py, bots

My bot run on Windows, with python. It's work fine but sometime, it's turn offline. When I go to my PC to see if the programe had stop I see that it's not closed and still work, with no error. Is that a discord api error ?

Comment: Please add the code to reproduce the problem, and the full traceback of the error message. See [mre]

Comment: i don't now the part that was doing that and i have no error, I just want to now what can disconnect the bot from discord

Comment: That's okay, just add the entire code to the problem. Try removing parts of it to see if the error still occurs with/without it.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer may be going in sleep mode, and that may explain why when you turn it on it looks like it is still going. I could be wrong since you have not provided any code, but that is my understanding of the situation.